# Install failed with django-keyboard-shortcuts 0.0.7 by pip in django 2.0.6

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install `django-keyboard-shortcut` via `pip`

```
pip install django-keyboard-shortcuts
```

I am using python 3.6.

My error:

```
Collecting django-keyboard-shortcuts
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/00/743c60d56a50cab02ca
8c2a2177b63e5b4548f3ce4293604422ad6651f67/django-keyboard-shortcuts-0.0.7.tar.gz

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\BRACKE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mpf8o833\django-key
board-shortcuts\setup.py", line 121, in <module>
        long_description=read('README.rst'),
      File "C:\Users\BRACKE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mpf8o833\django-key
board-shortcuts\setup.py", line 12, in read
        return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *parts)).read
()
      File "c:\users\bracketline\bracketnew\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, i
n decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8439:
 character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BRACKE~1
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mpf8o833\django-keyboard-shortcuts\
```

Comment: This package was last updated 7 years ago. I'm not sure whether it supports Python 3.

Comment: Its supporting on mac not on windows?